# Is there a way to check if a lambda was executed every more than a day and turn on an alarm? AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a lambda which is executed every monday and wednesday at 4pm and i need to know and trigger an alarm 5 minutes after the execution if the lambda wasn't executed.

I have a lambda which is executed every monday and wednesday at 4pm. This lambda prints a log to CloudWatch to indicate the start/end of the execution. So i need to check and turn on an alarm on cloudwatch at 4:05 pm ( 5 minutes after the execution) on monday and also on wednesday (monday is the first execution which is the start, and wednesday is the end, every week).

I noticed that I can create a new lambda that runs every monday and wednesday at 4:05pm, and get all the logs and find the logs related to the execution to confirm if it was executed ok or not and then that lambda could send notifications. I don't know if that solution is well, because I feel i can do the same with just metrics and alarms.
I tried with the metrics called "Invocations" but i got stuck quickly (i dont know how to manage the the execution just five minutes after the execution on monday and wednesday)

Comment: If you go with the 4pm Lambda and 4:05pm Lambda solution, how would that avoid the 4:05pm invocation failing to run for the exact same reason as the 4pm invocation failed to run e.g. degraded Lambda service? What are the consequences of the 4pm Lambda running? What does it do (other than write logs)? Perhaps the absence of that outcome should be the thing that triggers your alert.

Comment: you're right, it's not a good solution but it could help a little more (e.g when the 4pm lambda is disabled by accident).
The 4pm lambda just prints some logs and modifies some rows in database. I think is not very complicated to do with cloudwatch and alarms, but im stuck

Comment: I'm not sure that CloudWatch Alarms is ideal here. Your system is doing nothing for a long time then something at a very specific point in time. Alarms work on values relative to a threshold over a number of time periods. Your simplest bet might be 2 Lambda functions (worker at time T and tracker at T+5m). The worker writes a start message e.g. to DynamoDB, does work, then writes an end message to DynamoDB. The tracker runs at T+5 and queries DynamoDB for status, deleting the start/end pair if present, alarming if not.